# how to pre-populate spring properties from tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've a slight race condition when it comes to loading spring properties for an integration test using `@TestPropertySource`.

Consider the following;

**test (using Spock but same for JUnit)**

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test/simple-test.properties")
class SimpleStuff  extends Specification {

    public static final String inputDirectoryLocation = "/tmp/input-test-folder"

    def "test method"() {
        //do test stuff
    }
}
```

**simple-test.properties**

```
inputDirectoryLocation=/tmp/input-test-folder
```

**Spring Component**

```
@Component
class SpringComponent {

    @Value('${inputDirectoryLocation}')
    String inputDirectory;

//do other stuff
}
```

The above works fine but how would I make the test fully isolated and NOT have a dependency on the FileSystem having the folder  **/tmp/input-test-folder** (as not all users running this test are allowed to create a /tmp folder on their FS)

For example, I would like to use something like

```
inputDirectoryLocation = Files.createTempDirectory()
```

so that

```
@Value('${inputDirectoryLocation}')
String inputDirectory;//equals the output of Files.createTempDirectory()
```

resulting in test using the OS default temporary folder location & allows us to have the test simply delete the temp folder on cleanup. Is there an eloquent solution to solve the above?

*Note: using Spring boot 1.5*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out simple enough - simply had to change the value in the properties file to refer to the

```
inputDirectoryLocation=${java.io.tmpdir}/input-test-folder
```

Then have my Spock specification create the temp folder prior to launching Spring (by using the `setup()` fixture method )